# Drupal Importing Content from Feed

Tags: drupal, rss, drupal-6

I need to import Twitter posts (single account) into a Drupal site to display in a sidebar. Obviously I can use the pluggable JS script, but I don't want the page to hang waiting for a response from Twitter.

I installed the new Feeds module, but I am a little confused. I want to create a content type. This content is created from the RSS feed of tweets. However, it would seem that Feeds does not allow me to create multiple feed sources to create different types of content with? Is that true? Does it merge all imported RSS into a single content type?

The reason I ask is because I don't want everything merged into Feed Items, I'd like imported content to be mapped to different content types for Views displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this out, if I add a New Importer, I can do what I was looking for. Kind of sucks to have to create so many content types though.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at the [activitystream](http://drupal.org/project/activitystream) module, I think it does more or less what you want.

I use it on my personal site and it works ok, trying to get patches in is not paticularly easy mind you.

Comment: The Feeds module does do what Kevin is looking for, and it does a pretty nice job.